# is that possible to open and preview back-facing and front-facing camera at same time?

Tags: android-camera

I'm using HTC sensation for testing.
the version of Android is 2.3.4.
and there are two cameras on this device.

I could open camera separated (do preview NOT at same time).
BUT, once, if I try to open camera at same time.
I'll got a RuntimeException - Fail to connect to camera service for front-facing camera.

does anyone have idea ??

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Camera Api,

> *Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time
>   for a particular hardware camera.*

So I guess it should not be possible.